# Путь к картинкам в JAR файле

Tags: java, файлы

Собрал проект мавеном в JAR файл. Внутри архива есть папка с картинками, однако не могу понять, как прописать путь к этим файлам так, чтобы можно было открывать программу на любом компьютере без танцев с бубном, типа извлечения папки с картинками из JAR-архива. Сейчас прописано вот так

```
Image boom = new ImageIcon("images\\bomb.gif").getImage();
```

Программа обращается к файлу C:\Users\Сергей\desktop\images\bomb.gif, если JAR скидываю на рабочий стол

Comment: файлы с картинками лежат в resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить *URL* ресурса используйте **getClass().getResource()**;

```
getClass().getResource("/images/bomb.gif")
```

Сначала файл будет искаться в **classpath**/images/bomb.gif

если не найден то в: **jar-файл**/images/bomb.gif