# Java. Как использовать properties из артифакта JAR?

Tags: java, jar, properties

Все привет. Возник вопрос:

У меня есть программа, которая использует настройки из файла properties. Когда я собираю JAR-артефакт, все перестает работать. Я так подозреваю из-за того, что в коде у меня жестко прописаны пути в файлу. Как указать программе, что читать properties надо из JAR-файла?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654350/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B2-jar-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5/654389#654389

Comment: Да, это помогло. Спасибо!
А как быть с записью в properties?

Comment: никак. записывайте в другой файл - вне jar.