# Почему не отображаются иконки в TreeItem javaFX элементах хотя в режиме отладки всё работает правильно?

Tags: java, javafx

[image: SelectedTreeItem in Debugger][Это изображение при вызове Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Do1.jpg)  [Путь к картинкам в JAR файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654350/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b2-jar-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5) - не решает этот вопрос.

Код метода назначения графики в расширенном классе TreeItem:

```
private void autosetIcon() {

    String test = new FileTypesFilter(path).filterFileByType();

    // Getting the type of selected MyTreeItem
    switch (test) {
        case "folder":

            if (this.getVisited() == true) {
                try {
                    String imgFoldeClosedString = "icoes\\folder_opened.png";
                    Image imgOpenFolder = new Image(imgFoldeClosedString);
                    ImageView imgViewOpenFolder = new ImageView(imgOpenFolder);
                    Node foImgNode = new ImageView(imgOpenFolder);
                    this.setGraphic(foImgNode);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            } else if (this.getVisited() == false) {
                try {
                    String imgFolderOpenedString = "icoes\\folder_closed.png";
                    Image imgClosedFolder = new Image(imgFolderOpenedString);
                    ImageView imgViewClosedFolder = new ImageView(imgClosedFolder);
                    Node fcImgNode = new ImageView(imgClosedFolder);
                    this.setGraphic(imgViewClosedFolder);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            break;

        case "archive":
            try {
                String imgArchiveFolderString = "icoes\\archive.png";
                Image imgArch = new Image(imgArchiveFolderString);
                ImageView imgArchiveFile = new ImageView(imgArch);
                this.setGraphic(imgArchiveFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            break;

        case "exe":
            try {
                String imgExeFolderString = "icoes\\exe.png";
                Image imgExeFile = new Image(imgExeFolderString);
                ImageView imgViewExeFile = new ImageView(imgExeFile);
                this.setGraphic(imgViewExeFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            break;

        case "office":
            try {
                String imgOfficeFileString = "icoes\\office.png";
                Image imgOfficeFile = new Image(imgOfficeFileString);
                ImageView imgViewOfficeFile = new ImageView(imgOfficeFile);
                this.setGraphic(imgViewOfficeFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            break;

        case "web":
            try {
                String imgWebFileString = "icoes\\web.png";
                Image imgWebFile = new Image(imgWebFileString);
                ImageView imgViewWebFile = new ImageView(imgWebFile);
                this.setGraphic(imgViewWebFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            break;

        case "picture":
            try {
                String imgPictureFileString = "icoes\\picture.png";
                Image imgPictureFile = new Image(imgPictureFileString);
                ImageView imgViewPictureFile = new ImageView(imgPictureFile);
                this.setGraphic(imgViewPictureFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            break;

        case "multimedia":
            try {
                String imgMultimediaFileString = "icoes\\multimedia.png";
                Image imgMultimediaFile = new Image(imgMultimediaFileString);
                ImageView imgViewMultimediaFile = new ImageView(imgMultimediaFile);
                this.setGraphic(imgViewMultimediaFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            break;

        case "others":
            try {

                String imOtherFileString = "icoes\\other.png";
                Image imgOtherFile = new Image(imOtherFileString);
                ImageView imgViewOtherFile = new ImageView(imgOtherFile);
                this.setGraphic(imgViewOtherFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Это элемент кода из файлового менеджера. В этом методе назначаются иконки папкам и файлам в зависимости от их состояния и типа. При запуске в режиме отладки, всё прорисовывается, но когда программа запускается нормальным способом иконок не видно.... не успевают что ли???

Вывод стэктрейса при запуске приложения с помощью Run:

```
Executing D:\NBJavaEE\FileManager\dist\run1557390151\FileManager.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre/bin/java
Override ignored for property "run.jvmargs"
Override ignored for property "run.jvmargs.ide"
When using 'jar' attribute classpath-settings are ignored. See the manual for more information.
Executing 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java' with arguments:
'-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
'-classpath'
'D:\NBJavaEE\FileManager\dist\run1557390151\FileManager.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\plugin.jar'
'-jar'
'D:\NBJavaEE\FileManager\dist\run1557390151\FileManager.jar'
The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fileManagerTools.PathedTreeItem.autosetIcon(PathedTreeItem.java:119)
    at fileManagerTools.PathedTreeItem.<init>(PathedTreeItem.java:41)
    at filemanager.FXMLDocumentController.lambda$null$0(FXMLDocumentController.java:131)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Участок кода, где возникает **NPE**

```
try {
    String imgFolderOpenedString = "icoes\\folder_closed.png";

    /* Здесь выбрасывает NullPointerException */
    Image imgClosedFolder = new Image(PathedTreeItem.class.getClass().getResource(imgFolderOpenedString).toExternalForm());

    ImageView imgViewClosedFolder = new ImageView(imgClosedFolder);
    this.setGraphic(imgViewClosedFolder);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Путь к картинкам в JAR файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654350/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b2-jar-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Comment: я посмотрел ваш репозиторий. и могу вам с уверенность сказать - проблема в путях и организации проекта. я бы вам рекомендовал освоить систему сборки и создать правильную структуру директорий.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65547/discussion-on-question-by-fedulov-oleg------treeitem).

Answer (score 0):

- Правильный ответ про отрисовку иконок такой - 
  ImageView в JavaFX является Node ! а в свойствах этого класса сказано - A Node can only be contained in a single Parent element at the same time in JavaFX. В смысле нельзя один Node назначать нескольким Parent - ам.
  Поэтому для нормальной работы отрисовки иконок в файловом менеджере нужно при назначении картинок каждому элементу файловой системы создавать новый new ImageView() и устанавливать его в нужный TreeItem или его расширение.